# Open and closed questions. close and open or only open questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Now, i watch 62,571 questios beside of screen.

Question is , Are those open and closed questions or only open questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It includes closed questions as well. [Go to the last page and you can see it for yourself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions?page=1252&sort=votes).

Comment: How to count them?

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh search for `is:question closed:yes` (if you don't know how to get at that answer, click `Advanced Search Tips` next to the search box on a search result page)